# CSS button - transparent arrow on both sides

Tags: css, less, css-shapes

I am trying to create the button below by using the pseudo-elements before and after. **I do not want to manipulate the HTML DOM. I'm searching for a solution with pure CSS.**

[image]

How is it possible to make the currently white border-color of these triangles transparent?

**//EDIT:** The [marked topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27720098/oblique-or-twisted-border-shape) does not answer my question because I need a different angle than just rotating a square. It is also not transparent. I don't want to manipulate the DOM.

**//SOLVED:** This is the result after using Kate Millers solution:

[image]

**//EDIT2:** There is another problem with the solution I use now:

[image: The border-width changes depending on the zoom level of the browser]

Is there a way to fix the border-width of the triangles (left and right)?
Here you can see how the size changes to 14.4 and 26.4px, 26.4px:
[image]

Comment: I shouldn't self promote but have you had a look at my answer in that thread? It doesn't use SVG and the angle isn't exactly 90deg as in a square either. It uses two perspective rotated pseudo-elements.

Comment: You can have a look at this one also - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38006705/how-to-make-a-button-with-an-obtuse-angle/38006789#38006789. Your question **is not a** dupe of this one but it would give you an idea on how to create triangles with an angle other than 90deg.

Comment: Thank you @Harry your solution looks good, but I have two problems with this one: 1. It is fixed width   2. the angle changes after changing the width.

Comment: You're welcome @SimonHagmann. Yes, you can remove the fixed width. Just add a `display: inline-block` to make it as wide as the text. But fixed height is required. One more thing to note is that the angle of the triangle will vary based on the width of the element and that's unavoidable with this approach.

Comment: If the angle needs to remain the same then I'd suggest using a couple of triangles at either end with the approach that I used in the other answer (second comment). If you still find it unusable, I'll reopen the question for you.

Comment: I would need 2 triangles on each side - which is not possible just with one DOM Element. Fixed height would not be a problem but the angle has to be the same. I think I have to get more answers to get the proper solution.

Comment: Ok, I'll reopen it for you. It is possible to do with single element + maintain angle but I don't have the time now. Maybe somebody else will give you the answer.

Comment: Ok, thank you Harry! I'm looking forward for more answers.

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/7xex5k5f/1/) is a demo with borders and transparent arrow on both sides. The version with borders alone is fully transparent whereas the version with background color has triangles whose background just match the body background. If that helps you, I can post either only the version with borders (or) both as an answer.

Comment: As you said fixed height is not a problem for you, even a gradient based approach like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/87t019qg/) would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to reverse the triangles (so you're adding top and bottom triangles that match the button, but not on the sides). You can technically make "transparent" triangles, but you can't have that transparency apply to a different object.

One of the most important things I changed was that the background color and padding of the button has to apply to the span element (which means each button will need an interior span), not .btn.

If you replace all of your CSS about the buttons with the below, you'll have a solution that gets you at least 90% of the way there. The angle isn't perfect because it's stopping at the text. If you want to make the angle truly perfect, you'll probably need to do some absolute positioning, which would make it messy as your button sizes change.

The non-code way you can also achieve this is to create a .png or .svg with triangles that match the color of your button and insert them into the :before and :after with content: ' ';

```css
body { margin: 20px; background:#c2c2c2; }

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.btn {
  padding: 11px 40px;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  background: #a00;
}

.btn:before, .btn:after {
  content: '';
  border-top: 20px solid #a00;
  border-bottom: 20px solid #a00;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.btn:before {
  border-left:20px solid transparent;
  left: -20px;
}

.btn:after {
  border-right:20px solid transparent;
  right:-20px;
}


.btn.inset:before, .btn.inset:after {
  content: '';
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.btn.inset:before {
  border-right:20px solid #a00;
  left: -40px;
}

.btn.inset:after {
  border-left:20px solid #a00;
  right:-40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">Text in my little banner button</div>
<div class="btn inset">Text in my little banner button</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Kate for your solution, but there is still a manipulation of the DOM nessessary (span). Is it possible to get rid of this tag?

Comment: YES! I updated it and now you don't need the span tag and it makes the angles perfect. You'll just need to make sure the left: and right: are the negative of whatever you make the border-right: or border-left: values.

Comment: Ok thanks for the hint. Can I also just display the border of this shape or do I have do use the code from the marked topic (OP)?

Comment: I ignored the `.is--primary {
  border-radius: 0;
  background: #a9825c;
  border: 0 none;
}
.is--large {
  height: 53px;
  padding: 0px 60px 0px 60px;
}`, but the rest of my code should replace the rest of your code.

Comment: It works in my code. I also need to create the same button only with the border like in this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27720414/5016779). Can I also to this somehow with your code? The mentioned post has a fixed width and a variable angle..

Comment: I've updated the above to include a second button style — you'll notice that the parts of the border that were colored before are now transparent. The left: and right: values now need to be **twice** and negative of what the border-left: and border-right: values are (and -left and -right switched)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121669/discussion-between-simon-hagmann-and-kate-miller).

Answer (score 1):

I don't use, and am not really familiar with, LESS... but you can create a similar element using a span and a wrapper with pseudo elements. It does take 2 triangles for each side (hence the span).

```css
body { margin: 20px; background: #ddd; }

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 11px 40px;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  background: #a00;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.btn:after,
.btn span:after,
.btn:before,
.btn span:before {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
}
.btn:after {
  top: 0;
  border-right-color: #ddd;
  border-bottom-color: #ddd;
  }
.btn span:after {
  bottom: 0;
  border-right-color: #ddd;
  border-top-color: #ddd;
}
.btn:before {
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  border-left-color: #ddd;
  border-bottom-color: #ddd;
  }
.btn span:before {
  bottom: 0;
  left:0;
  border-left-color: #ddd;
  border-top-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn"><span>Text in my little banner button</span></div>
```

I realize the ends aren't *really* transparent, they just match the background color to *appear* transparent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Scott. The arrows are not really transparent so there is still a whitespace between the shape and the background. I also can not change the DOM structure in this case.

Comment: No problem, Simon. I don't know how you could pull this off with *truly* transparent ends and *not* altering the DOM without using images/sprites.